# Use css of one theme into another

Tags: magento2, theme, css

I want to use `CSS` from `.less` file of one theme into another theme `phtml` file. There are two theme in my `Magento 2.3` site.
How can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to solve is a dependency between theme A and theme B which means you need to use [theme inheritance](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-inherit.html), if you don't want a parent/child theme relationship then you should copy and paste the LESS file over.